# ItemType for System.Linq.IGrouping when using Strongly-Typed Data Controls gives "Could not load type" error

Tags: asp.net, linq, webforms, repeater

I am trying to display a Linq grouping result using repeater control.  My ASPx code is as follows:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ItemType="System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.Int32, myProject.Student]">
    <ItemTemplate>
        Age: <%# Item.Key %> / Count <%# Item.Count() %>
        //Maybe another repeater for each record in the group
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

and the Select method is:

```
public System.Linq.IGrouping<Int32, myProject.Student> Repeater_StudentByAge_GetData()
    {
        return new context().Student.GroupBy(x=>x.Age);
    }
```

Visual Studio IntelliSense works well with my ItemType declaration, but when running I receive the following error:

`Could not load type'System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.Int32, myProject.Student]'.`

May I know what is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Just save yourself the trouble and introduce a class for the item in the repeater. It will be easier to read and maintain.